# For Loop is Iterating Once when the Value of i=lastSize

Tags: android, multithreading, for-loop, animation, delay

I am not much experienced in Android Programming, So I am stuck with a problem where I want to animate till the arraySize(). But the loop iterates only once.Actually I need to apps animation where every app start animated after haphazard delay time. For better understanding I am here Posting my Detailed Code.
 I have been taking this problem for since 2 days and could not find any solution so i decide to post here.

```
  @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


                Animation cout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.optimization);
                fan_bg.setAnimation(cout);
                animateprogress(mHoloCircularProgressBar);//b8=b7+1;

                int remainder = ramOptimizeArrayList.size() / 8;

                int b = 0;
                for ( int i=0;i<= remainder;i++) {

                    b = b + 1;
                    top.setImageDrawable(ramOptimizeArrayList.get(b).getIconlink2());
                    b = b + 1;
                    top_left.setImageDrawable(ramOptimizeArrayList.get(b).getIconlink2());
                    b = b + 1;
                    top_right.setImageDrawable(ramOptimizeArrayList.get(b).getIconlink2());
                    b = b + 1;
                    left.setImageDrawable(ramOptimizeArrayList.get(b).getIconlink2());
                    b = b + 1;
                    right.setImageDrawable(ramOptimizeArrayList.get(b).getIconlink2());
                    b = b + 1;
                    bottom.setImageDrawable(ramOptimizeArrayList.get(b).getIconlink2());
                    b = b + 1;
                    bottom_left.setImageDrawable(ramOptimizeArrayList.get(b).getIconlink2());
                    b = b + 1;
                    bottom_right.setImageDrawable(ramOptimizeArrayList.get(b).getIconlink2());

                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    top_right.startAnimation(top_left_anim);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    };

                    Handler handler1 = new Handler();
                    handler1.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

                    Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    top.startAnimation(top_anim);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    };

                    Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                    handler3.postDelayed(runnable2, 50);

                    Runnable runnable4 = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    top_left.startAnimation(top_right_anim);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    };

                    Handler handler4 = new Handler();
                    handler4.postDelayed(runnable4, 200);


                    Runnable runnable5 = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    left.startAnimation(left_anim);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    };

                    Handler handler5 = new Handler();
                    handler5.postDelayed(runnable5, 500);


                    Runnable runnable6 = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    right.startAnimation(right_anim);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    };

                    Handler handler6 = new Handler();
                    handler6.postDelayed(runnable6, 300);

                    Runnable runnable7 = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    bottom_left.startAnimation(bottom_left_anim);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    };

                    Handler handler7 = new Handler();
                    handler7.postDelayed(runnable7, 600);

                    Runnable runnable8 = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    bottom.startAnimation(bottom_anim);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    };

                    Handler handler8 = new Handler();
                    handler8.postDelayed(runnable8, 350);

                    Runnable runnable9 = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    bottom_right.startAnimation(bottom_right_anim);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    };

                    Handler handler9 = new Handler();
                    handler9.postDelayed(runnable9, 650);
                }
            /*top.startAnimation(top_anim);
            top_left.startAnimation(top_right_anim);
            left.startAnimation(left_anim);
            right.startAnimation(right_anim);
            bottom_left.startAnimation(bottom_left_anim);
            bottom.startAnimation(bottom_anim);
            bottom_right.startAnimation(bottom_right_anim);*/
                }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why all the `b=b+1` lines? This looks like it should be a loop.

Comment: Similarly, every variable name that ends with a number indicates that you should be using a looping structure.

Comment: No offence but you need some serious refactoring of the code :)

Comment: As for your actual problem, you should learn how to use the Android Studio debugger.

Comment: well this was just a sample code i'll finalize it before deliverable. Actually i want animations on every image and animation have some delay due to i think this loop is iterating once....

Comment: `ramOptimizeArrayList.size() / 8` for remainder is not a good value for looping in the array size. `ramOptimizeArrayList.size()` will do

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna `iterate` till `array size`, why are you using remainder in the `loop`. You have set the remainder value to:

```
int remainder = ramOptimizeArrayList.size() / 8;
```

Since `remainder` is int, if the `array size` is say `13`:
`remainder = 13/8`, which turns out to be `1`, since `remainder` is an `integer`.

Write your for loop as:

```
for ( int i=0;i<= ramOptimizeArrayList.size();i++) {
//rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Actually i want animations on every image and animation have some delay due to i think this loop is iterating once....